# Drop Down Box (CSS,JS,HTML,BBCode)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to set up a BB code for a forum that I help run.

I am using the following code to create a drop down box that users can put in the signature field of their user profiles:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">My Characters</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a>{text}</a>
  </div>
</div>
<head>
<style>
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    border: 1px dotted !important;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  border-color:white !important;
  color: white;
min-width: 500px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: Black;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
 z-index: 500 !important;
min-width: 500px !important;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
position: absolute !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
border: 1px solid !important;
    border-color: white !important;
  background-color: rgba(20,20,21,0.95) !important;
  min-width: 500px;
    max-height: 250px !important;
  z-index: 500 !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    }

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
</style>
<body>
</body>
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The issue is that only the first dropdown box on each page works. The others do not respond to clicks. Is there a way to get multiple dropdowns to work simultaneously, without directly referencing each drop down in the code?

Comment: Have you tried using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)?

Answer (score 0):

You're using same ID for every dropdown; remember ID's must be unique. Remove ID and send clicked item to the function.

Inside function, use clicked item to get *parentNode* and find the container by its class, then show or hide with `togle()`:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(item) {
  item.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    border: 1px dotted !important;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  border-color:white !important;
  color: white;
min-width: 500px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: Black;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
 z-index: 500 !important;
min-width: 500px !important;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
/*    position: absolute !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0); */
border: 1px solid !important;
    border-color: white !important;
  background-color: rgba(20,20,21,0.95) !important;
  color:#fff;
  min-width: 500px;
    max-height: 250px !important;
  z-index: 500 !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    }

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this);" class="dropbtn">My Characters</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a>{text}</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this);" class="dropbtn">My Other Characters</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a>{text}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```